# ¿Como codificar y decodificar strings con JS ahorrando cantidad de letras, sin base64?

Tags: javascript, string

pues tengo la necesidad de codificar o decodificar string ahorrando tamaños de letras. Por ejemplo si tengo
 `"Este_es_un_string"` 
y quisiera codificarlo que diera un resultado por ejemplo `sT1M-0AA4eD`.

Pensaba en algo como borrar las vocales del string, quedando como resultado `"st_s_n_strng"` Pues aun funciona, pero sería algo que podría repetirse como por ejemplo `calor` => `clr`, y para `color` daria igual, sería `clr`

Quisiera saber como podria ahorrarme cantidad de caracteres en un string... Sin necesidad de seguridad, solo que no se repitiese como calor y color...

Y pues que se puede decodificar si es posible para poder leer el string "codiicado".

Comment: Lo que pides es matematicamente imposible.

Comment: Si, quizá algo dificil, pero no diría que implosible... Si no hay forma pues me toca buscar una opción que funcione :(